# Does the enemy AI have sight cheats?

Tags: cheats, battlefleet-gothic-armada

In recent games against the AI in Battlefleet Gothic: Armada (BFGA), I've grown more and more suspicious that the AI can actually has you identified (or at least a red blip) at all times.

They appear perfectly able to fire weapons or actions that require identification( like homing missiles) at times when they shouldn't be able to see you at all (such as when you are hiding in a cloud).

Along with this, they don't appear to have any trouble following a ship that is running silent, hiding in a nebula, or has a "This ship doesn't appear at all" skill active. I know everything I listed completely hides you completely because the enemy AI employs it against me all the time and I had hoped to do the same thing back at them.

So are they able to see you at all times no matter what you are doing or is there something important I have missed?

Answer (score 1):

It would appear so.

I can't tell for sure (though I suppose someone with sufficient knowledge could mine the game files for a direct answer or proof), but in general the easiest way of making capable bots is giving them an unfair advantage over the player.